# How to get block and views results to display in the search result page?

Tags: 7, views, blocks, search

I'm using Drupal7 default search for content(node). For some pages I have integerated drupal blocks and view blocks. While searching for specific string in search which are available in blocks are not showing up in search result.

I have verified that the content in the site is fully indexed (100%), still the texts available in the blocks are not returning any results when searched.

I have also tried the [Search by Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_by_page) module, it doesn't help either. How can I make every page in the site to be indexed and display results when queried for?

Comment: Search doesn't search the content of blocks if that is what you are thinking. Nor Views results. Just nodes. Search by page does mention Views but not Blocks. are you trying to find content in custom blocks?

Comment: Yes I know Site search won't return blocks or views result, What I am asking is that, Is there any way to include them in the search results ?

Comment: Will adding Apache Solr search or google search module able to display block and views content in search result? or its not even possible to display them in search result?

Comment: Apache solr won't help. Google search may as it is probably indexing you're rendered pages which is why Search by Page may have worked. Could you instead create nodes for your block content and then display those nodes in blocks? Search would return the node path rather than the page with the block though. Sounds like you are trying to hack something together with blocks that works be better done with a different layout mechanism like Panels.

Comment: I tried Search by page module but it didn't fetch me blocks and views result in search result.

Comment: Sounds like a configuration issue as that's what it says it does on the box.

Comment: It seems like Search by module only displays the region "content" block alone. Not able to get other region blocks results . Is there anything can be done to fetch those results too ?

Comment: It says Views on the box. If that's not working either then you config must we off. But like I said this isn't how search works. Blocks aren't really content.